# WP Cron doesn't save <iframe> or <object> in post body

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, security, wp-cron, iframe

I am using `wp_cron` to auto grab posts from a remote website and save them in my wp db.

**NOTICE! I am executing my code from my plugin, not from my template functions.php or somewhere else. I have my own validation of grabbed content to prevent malicious code etc. so turning off security validation in wordpress is not an issue in my case, but be careful if you don't have your own validation of grabbed content. Always validate grabbed values  if possible!**

I have in my plugin one button to grab posts manually by clicking on this button and it works perfect. Everything is stored as I want in my database. No problem here.

but then I have a `wp_cron` function that runs for testing purposes every two minutes (if somebody clicks on my page, of course ;) and here is a problem.

Notice that the code is identical, just instead of `get_user_id()` I set it manualy to `1`. that's probably the only change between these two codes.

And the problem is that everything is stored as expected including time, title, slug, (it even grabs and downnload and set the featured image for the post correctly), tags, categories and additional taxonomy too. So that fine.

Only thing that is missing is the body text (content) of the post.

When downloaded from admin manually. It's something like:

```
<iframe width="650" scrolling="no" height="450" frameborder="0" src="http://example.com/embedframe/3843634"></iframe>
```

or

```
<object height="450" width="650" ><param name="movie" ... bla bla bla ... shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="450" width="650" /></object>
```

So, it is because it is filtered and striped out, I mean `object` and `iframe` when not logged in as an admin?

If so, how can I turn it off in my plugin?

Or is it something else?

I really think it's only something with WP security issue, because the code works when performed from admin as admin manually. And the code of the function is the same and all variables are passed in as expected. Just content is not saved.

**EDIT:**

It's definitely **something with the WP security**. When I set in my auto cron function content variable manually to "Testing auto save." is is saved normally. But When I set it to `<iframe>something</iframe>` or `<object>blablabal</object>` it is NOT.

**How to turn this "checking" off, so I can save my code with cron?**

Any idea?

Comment: It's definitely something with the WP security. When I set in my auto cron function content variable manualy to "Testing auto save." is is saved normally. But When I set it to `<iframe>something</iframe>` or `<object>blablabal</object>` it is not. How to turn this check off, so I can save my code with cron?

Comment: You need to insert those posts as admin. Please use the search, this has been discussed before (sorry I'm a little short here). It's basically to hook in there and raise the user-level when this is a cron request - I think it was lowered for some reason so better understand the implications.

Comment: No, I finally solved it ;) . You need to use `remove_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
 remove_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');` and do wp_insert_post(); and then turn it on if you want to feel protected against some "injection" ;) like `add_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
 add_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');`

Comment: Well, that's probably not really sane because you likely will disable as well for comments or so. I dunno specifically, but I can only suggest you really take care of side-effects here.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manually removing the safety filters like this, you should simply set the correct user for these processes to be running as.

When you are logged in and running a process manually, you are *logged in* and thus you have your credentials being used, and your permissions being used. I'm betting you're an administrator on the site. You have permission to post unfiltered_html, meaning that you can post iframes and objects and whatever you like.

When your cron job runs, it doesn't have your credentials. So, it doesn't get those same permissions. Thus, the safety filters get turned on, and things like iframes and such get blocked.

To fix it, you need to change your process not to disable the filters, but to run *as you*. So find your user ID number in the database, and just before your process to do the import runs, add this code:

`wp_set_current_user( 123 );`

Where "123" is whatever your user ID number is. Then the code will now be "you" and can do things just like you would do them. Those filters won't take effect because the permissions are correct for the current user.

Note: This isn't any safer, BTW. You're still allowing some remote website to insert possibly dangerous things onto yours. So you're trusting them not to screw you over here. Just bear that in mind. This method is just simpler than manually fiddling around with filters.

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING !!!**

**Always make validation of the data you are saving into the database! This answer below assumes that you validate the content of your post inside of your custom function that you trigger via cron!**

I find solution to this problem of stripping iframe and object tags.

**NOTICE! Put this only in your plugin's function code that is run via wp cron. Don't put it in your function.php in your template or in other places.**

```
// before saving post
remove_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
remove_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');

// save code here

// after saving post
add_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
add_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
```

**IMPORTANT!**
By using the prefix `content_` we are limiting the `remove filter -> save our data -> add_filter` proces to just the content and not commetns, excerpt etc.

Comment: You removed the "security" so I *guess* you didn't solve much here. Better get some review by others first before suggesting this as a solution.

Comment: What are you talking about? I am using my own validation in my function.

Comment: This is a dangerous fix, and makes your site more unsecure

Comment: @Derfder: Then make that really visible within your answer. E.g. show the action around as code. Keep in mind other users might find this here via google and just copy and paste and really eat the pain. Hence the warning is important.

Comment: `This is a dangerous fix, and makes your site more unsecure` please, explain, why it's insecure if it's only in my plugin function that is called only once a day via wp cron?

Comment: @hakre I have added a notice that you should put this code only in your plugin with the function that is run via cron and not to the template functions.php file. I hope it's clearer now. Could you please remove the down vote, please? Thanks.

Comment: @Derfder: I did not downvote your answer, but I honor that you improved your answer. The notice is well placed. Also take care that you really control when that cron funcion is invoked. If others know about that they can use it to make you include malicious content into your site. This can get you bannings on google and so on. You should really take care with external content, iframe and object checks have been introduced for a reason.

Comment: Your pulling content from other sources, and disabling the security so you can display things like iframes and object elements. Whats to stop one of those sources putting script tags in there?

Comment: I was the one who downvoted

Comment: I have custom validation in my custom function to strip out things I don't want and malicious stuff. This is not a problem at all in my case.

Comment: Then make it clear in your answer, as it currently stands, any person may come across this, go AHA and copy paste, unaware of the consequences

Comment: Also sometimes things start to sound like excuses if they have not been pointed out from the beginning. Be lazy, but be lazy at the right place :)

Comment: I have already, check my question and answer and remove your downvote if possible, please.

Comment: I see no mention of validation or stripping routines/code in your answer

Comment: @TomJNowell try to reload this page or try empty your cache. I have put there this `NOTICE! Put this only in your plugin's function code that is run via wp cron. Don't put it in your function.php in your template or in other places.` It's in bold to catch the visitor attention.

Comment: @TomJNowell I have also added this to be even more specific for the reader of this question and answer `WARNING !!!

Always make validation of the data you are saving into the database! This answer below assumes that you validate the content of your post inside of your custom function that you trigger via cron!`

Comment: @TomJNowell please, remove you downvote, if possible. I tried my best to make my answer be understood even for a random visitor. Thank you Tom in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use shortcodes, e.g create an iframe shortcode, then you'd be able to do:

```
[iframe]example.com[/iframe]
```

Here's code to implement such a shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('iframe', array('iframe_shortcode', 'shortcode'));
class iframe_shortcode {
    function shortcode($atts, $content=null) {
          extract(shortcode_atts(array(
               'url'      => '',
               'scrolling'      => 'no',
               'width'      => '100%',
               'height'      => '500',
               'frameborder'      => '0',
               'marginheight'      => '0',
          ), $atts));
          if (empty($url)) return '<!-- Iframe: You did not enter a valid URL -->';
     return '<iframe src="'.$url.'" title="" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" scrolling="'.$scrolling.'" frameborder="'.$frameborder.'" marginheight="'.$marginheight.'"><a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">'.$url.'</a></iframe>';
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[iframe url="http://wpsnipp.com" width="100" height="100" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" marginheight="2"]
```

Source:

http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/iframe-shortcode-for-posts-and-pages/

If you need to insert object embeds, then something has gone wrong. Use OEmbed or devise a shortcode

Comment: Tanks, but I have a complex function and I grab also object, and other stuff. my function code is good I think I just needed wp_filter_post_kses to do what I want.

Comment: Complex functions are inherently harder to test, and easy to break. Perhaps you should be stripping iframes out of your content before saving it, and replacing them with shortcodes so that you dont compromise your security

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything, this worked for me:

```
global $allowedposttags;
$allowedposttags['div'] = array('align' => array (), 'class' => array (), 'id' => array (), 'dir' => array (), 'lang' => array(), 'style' => array (), 'xml:lang' => array() );
$allowedposttags['iframe'] = array('src' => array () );
```

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_update_post-strips-css-id-attribute?replies=7